# What could potentially cause a line-height variance despite the same OS/browser/hardware configuration?

Tags: css, safari

I have a user who is experiencing an issue with a site that I am completely unable to replicate. They have reported that they are using a Macbook Pro Retina 15", and running the latest version of Safari and Yosemite.

I've tried to replicate this on every device I can get my hands on with no luck (including using the exact OS/browser/hardware combo they have). Cache has been cleared on their end, zoom level has been reset.

Here's the screenshot comparison: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCKMs.jpg

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? Is there some Safari default line-height setting I'm missing?

Thanks to anyone who can shed light on this freaky issue.

Comment: [link to the site](http://mm.armyofbees.net)

Comment: You should include relevant code *in the question itself*. A link to a live page is not enough. And you should verbally describe what the issue is (and state what makes you think it is line-height variance).